# Raspberry Pi 3 can't boot up directly to the desktop

Tags: raspbian, retropie, raspi-config

I've got a Raspberry pi 3 with a Retropie installed on it.
I want to be able to boot it directly to the desktop, without having the need to type `startx` every time, as I prefer to boot the Retro machine from the Terminal on the desktop whenever I want to play.

I tried to configure it manually in the boot options under the `raspi-config` settings, so I chose `Desktop Auto-login - desktop GUI, automatically logged in as 'pi' user`, but it changed nothing.

So then I found the file
 `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` and saw that the relevant line was already written as

`ExecStart=-/sbin/getty/  --noclear -a root %I $TERM`

Important note: at the beginning of the boot the Pixel desktop appears for 3 seconds and then it immediately goes to the CLI.

What am I doing wrong/ what can I do more in order to change it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem on my pi 3 and solved it according to [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#LightDM_freezes_on_login_attempt):

reinstall the gdk-pixbuf2 and lightdm package and reboot.